# SQL Conditional Where

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a Stored Procedure called spGetOrders which accepts a few parameters:  @startdate and @enddate.  This queries an "Orders" table.  One of the columns in the table is called "ClosedDate".  This column will hold NULL if an order hasn't been closed or a date value if it has.  I'd like to add a @Closed parameter which will take a bit value.  In a simple world, I'd be able to do..

```
select * from orders o
where o.orderdate between @startdate AND @enddate
and (if @Closed = 1 then o.ClosedDate IS NULL else o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL)
```

Obviously, that's not going to work..  I'm also looking at dynamic sql which is my last resort, but starting to look like the answer..

Please help..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from orders o
where o.orderdate between @startdate AND @enddate
and ((@Closed = 1 And o.ClosedDate IS NULL) Or (@Closed = 0 And o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL))
```

Be vary careful about mixing AND's and OR's in the where clause.  When doing this, the parenthesis to control the order of evaluation is VERY important.

Comment: This is a great way to fix this problem. Thanks for this approach!

Answer (score 2):

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT *  
FROM orders  
WHERE orderdate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate  
AND (@Closed = 1 OR CLosedDate IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Watch out for your AND/OR issues - you need parentheses!

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
select * from orders o
where o.orderdate between @startdate AND @enddate
and (  (@Closed = 1 AND o.ClosedDate IS NULL)
     OR (ISNULL(@Closed, 0) <> 1 AND o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL)
     )
```

It looks like you want all the orders between two dates that have inconsistent Close information.  The other suggestions are probably as good (or better) but I'm pretty sure that this works and is readable to me (most of the other suggestions appeared as I was typing).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, write it out.

```
select * from orders o
where o.orderdate between @startdate AND @enddate
and ((@Closed = 1 and o.ClosedDate IS NULL)
    or (@Closed != 1 and o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL))
```

double, can be removed

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches one could take to conditional conditions of the form `if-then-else`, each of which differs in readability and performance. All approaches can also handle conditions of the form `if-then` by using a true value (`1`) for the else branch (as `if p then q` is logically equivalent to `if p then q else true`).

(Note: the condition shown in the question's code sample asserts that `closedDate` should be NULL when `@Closed` is true; this appears to be a logic mistake, as `@Closed` should be true to get closed orders, in which case `closedDate` *shouldn't* be null, as the question text rightly states. In this answer, the `NULL` tests are swapped to correct this error.)

### `IF` Function

Some RDBMSs have an `IF` function, which is closest to the question sample and conceptually simplest.

`IF(<test>, <then condition>, <else condition>)`

SQL Server provides [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql), which is equivalent to a `CASE` expression (see below). Since `@Close` basically contains a boolean value, it can be tested directly, rather than comparing to `1`. In the more general case, a comparison expression would be used.

`IF(@Closed, o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL, o.ClosedDate IS NULL)`

Note that since this uses column values within a function, queries using `IF` generally aren't [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/90527).

### `CASE` Operator

An `IF` function is fairly simple: a test picking among two alternatives. `CASE` expressions are a more general, allowing for an arbitrary number of alternatives. Consequently, you have a choice of what values to handle as alternatives.

There are two forms of `CASE`, simple and searched. In a simple `CASE`, a value at the top is compared to values listed for each alternative. In a searched `CASE`, each alternative has its own expression, which are evaluated independently as [booleans](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boolean-expressions-in-sql/).

```
-- simple: compare top <expression> to each WHEN <expression>
CASE <expression>
  WHEN <expression> THEN ...
  ...
  ELSE ...
END

-- searched: test each <expression>
CASE 
  WHEN <expression> THEN ...
  ...
  ELSE ...
END
```

When used for a conditional condition, a searched expression is the simplest, and corresponds closely to an `if-then-else`. For the case in question:

```
CASE 
  WHEN @Closed THEN o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL
  ELSE o.ClosedDate IS NULL
END
```

If the test is more complex than a boolean variable, a searched expression makes even more sense to pick. The simple form may make sense if the test is a single value that you're comparing to, though you have to decide whether & how to handle values beyond what you expect. You could explicitly list all expected values, and handle other values as passing:

```
CASE @Closed
  WHEN 1 THEN o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL
  WHEN 0 THEN o.ClosedDate IS NULL
  ELSE 1
END
```

You could also handle unexpected values as failing, or cause an error.

You could handle just one value, treating all others as the alternative:

```
CASE @Closed
  WHEN 1 THEN o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL
  ELSE o.ClosedDate IS NULL
END

-- or
CASE @Closed
  WHEN 0 THEN o.ClosedDate IS NULL
  ELSE o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL
END
```

Which to pick depends on the business rules.

`CASE` expressions generally aren't sargable, especially as they often involve calculating values from columns (though you should always check the query execution plan to be sure).

### Logical Operators

A logical consequence, `if p then q` (in logic, also written `p implies q`, or `p ⇒ q`) is logically equivalent to `not p or q` (in logic, also written `¬p ∨ q`). There isn't a standard way of expressing the [logical ternary expression](https://cse.buffalo.edu/%7Erapaport/572/S02/ifthenelse.pdf), `if p then q else r` (in programming, `p ? q : r`) in terms of other logical operators, but there are two strong candidates:

1. `(if p then q) and (if not p then r)`, `(p ⇒ q) ∧ (¬p ⇒ q)`
2. `(if p then q and not r) and (if not p then not q and r)` `(p ⇒ q∧¬r) ∧ (¬p ⇒ ¬q∧r)`

Either of these could be the basis for rewriting `if-then-else` in terms of other logical operators:

```
-- interpretation 1
    (NOT <test> OR <then condition>) 
AND (    <test> OR <else condition>)

-- interpretation 2
    (NOT <test> OR (    <then condition> AND NOT <else condition>))
AND (    <test> OR (NOT <then condition> AND     <else condition>)
```

The result is less readable than `IF()` or `CASE`, but potentially has better performance.

For the case in question, since `q` and `r` are dependent on each other, only the 1st interpretation is worth consideration.

```
(@Closed OR o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL) AND (NOT @Closed OR o.ClosedDate IS NULL)
```

Showing that this reduces to the appropriate conditions is left as an exercise.

Since this expression is a combination of simple comparisons, it's likely sargable (though, again, check the query execution plan).

### `IF` and `CASE` Statements

In some contexts (such as stored procedures & functions), an `IF` or `CASE` statement can be used to pick among different queries. `IF` statements, like `CASE` and unlike `IF` functions, allow more than 2 alternatives (though that feature isn't needed here).

```
IF <test> THEN
  SELECT ... WHERE <then condition> ...
ELSE
  SELECT ... WHERE <else condition> ...
END IF
```

A `CASE` statement is different from a `CASE` operator; the two are distinguishable by:

- which grammatical contexts they occur in (roughly, the statement in procedures, the operator in queries),
- by what's allowed in the branches (roughly, the statement allows queries , the operator allows expressions), and
- the statement ends with `END CASE`.

A `CASE` statement is quite similar to an `IF` statement, especially in the searched form:

```
CASE
  WHEN <test> THEN
    SELECT ... WHERE <then condition> ...
  ELSE
    SELECT ... WHERE <else condition> ...
END CASE
```

These statements are more verbose and involve repeating code (which is a chance to introduce errors), but are the most sargable option if performance is an issue.

With the sample in question:

```
IF @Closed THEN
    SELECT *
      FROM Orders o
      WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
        AND o.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL;
ELSE
    SELECT *
      FROM Orders o
      WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
        AND o.ClosedDate IS NULL;
END IF;
```