# SQL - is conditional Where statement possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to implement a conditional Where and having problems.  What I want to do is select only those customers that visited a beauty salon that had a haircut and also a manicure in the past year.  The treatments don't have to be on the same day.  e.g.  If Susan had a manicure in the last 12 months, select all the times Susan had a haircut in the same time period.  The table is structured so each visit is one row.  e.g.

```
Customer     Treatment     Treatment_Date
Susan        Manicure      12 Jan 2013
Susan        Make-up       3 Feb 2013
Susan        Haircut       14 Feb 2013
Susan        Blow Dry      3 Mar 2013
Susan        Haircut       21 Apr 2013
Betty        Manicure      4 Jun 2013
Betty        Haircut       7 July 2013
Tara         Haircut       10 Aug 2013
```

So ideally I'd like to select Susan and Betty. Can this be done in one query or would it have to be broken up, like first select all customers that had a haircut, then from this select those that had a manicure.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

:)

Comment: Can you please post the SQL that you're working with?

Comment: Have a look at [SQL Conditional Where](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353425/sql-conditional-where)

Comment: _"So ideally I'd like to select **Susan** and Betty."_ Susan hasn't had a manicure in the past 12 months, though...

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer
  FROM
(
  SELECT Customer,
         MAX(CASE WHEN Treatment = 'Manicure' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) had_manicure,
         MAX(CASE WHEN Treatment = 'Haircut' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) had_haircut
    FROM table1 t
   WHERE Treatment_Date >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())
) q
 WHERE had_manicure + had_haircut = 2
```

Output:

```
| CUSTOMER |
|----------|
|    Betty |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e188/9)** demo

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  I like to solve these using `group by` and `having`:

```
select ct.Customer
from CustomerTreatment ct
where ct.Treatment_Date >= getdate() - 365
group by ct.Customer
having sum(case when ct.Treatment = 'Manicure' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when ct.Treatment = 'Haircut' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of treatments of each type.  Your conditions specify that each appears at least once, hence the `> 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Customer, Treatment, Treatment_Date From Treatments 
Where Customer In (Select Customer from Treatments Where Treatment = 'Manicure' And Treatment_Date >= Start_Date_For_The_Period_Goes_Here And Treatment_Date <= End_Date_For_The_Period_Goes_Here) 
And 
Customer In (
Select Customer from Treatments Where Treatment = 'Haircut' And Treatment_Date >= Start_Date_For_The_Period_Goes_Here And Treatment_Date <= End_Date_For_The_Period_Goes_Here
)
```

---

### Other ways : You may use a between clause. You may also use self-joins.

In other news, I wouldn't call this a conditional Where statement. I would call it one, if the Where clause contained a Case When Then End phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

Select
     Customer,

```
 count(case when treatment = 'manicure' then 1 else 0 end) as Manicure,
 count(case when treatment = 'haircut' then 1 else 0 end) as haircut
```

from

```
customerTreatment
```

where Treatment_date >= DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate())

```
group by Treatment

have count(Manicure) > 1 and count(haircut) > 1
```