# SQL conditional where, return all if condition not met

Tags: sql, t-sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a similar question to [SQL Conditional Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353425/sql-conditional-where) and [Conditional WHERE clause in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629132/conditional-where-clause-in-sql-server), except when the condition is not met, I want to return all rows (as if there were no WHERE clause).

One solution could be to do the following. Note that `<ColLetter>` and `<ColValue>` are string insertions, where `<ColLetter>` will be one of `ColA`, `ColB`, `ColC`, or `NULL`, and `<ColValue>` will be a value that can appear in one of those columns (or is `NULL` if the `<ColLetter>` is).

```
SELECT ID, ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM MainTable t
WHERE (
  -- <ColLetter> is not null, corresponding to a column name in MainTable
  (ISNULL(<ColLetter>, 0) <> 0 AND t.<ColLetter> =  <ColValue>)
  OR
  -- <ColLetter> is null, I want to return all rows
  (ISNULL(<ColLetter>, 0) = 0 AND t.ID is not null)
  )
```

The issue with this is that it checks the ID column for nulls unnecessarily (there won't be any nulls) and it is a large table. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
where case <colLetter>
     when '<nameOfColA>' then nameOfColA
     when '<nameOfColB>' then nameOfColB
     When '<nameOfColC>' then nameOfColC
     else isNull(<colValue>, 0) end 
      = isNull(<colValue>, 0)
```

Comment: Unless I am misreading this, I think you have misunderstood. `<colLetter>` will be the name of one of the non-ID columns if it is not null. `<colValue>` will be a value that can appear in a row of the specified column.

Comment: ok, yes, I think I get it. But you haven't told us those column names, so I had to use arbitrary names.  (You know what these are, right?)  Put the actual names in the SQL.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I have used dummy names but they may as well be the actual names. So there is a column call `ID`, there is a column called `ColA`, a column called `ColB` and a column called `ColC`. In reality there are many more columns and they have proper names (e.g. `Address`). This answer has still misunderstood the aim I think. My apologies if my explanation was poor!

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to

```
SELECT ID, ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM MainTable t
WHERE (
   -- <ColLetter> is null, I want to return all rows
   ISNULL(<ColLetter>, 0) = 0 
   -- Check the value otherwise
   OR t.<ColLetter> = <ColValue>)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Serg. You were very close, but in the case where `<ColLetter>` is not null, your version would have returned rows where `t.<ColLetter> = <ColValue>` AND where `<ColLetter>` is NULL. I've edited this accordingly (still awaiting peer review) and now it works as it should.

Comment: I see no edit. If you need to return NULL `t.<ColLetter>` in any case, `OR t.<ColLetter> IS NULL` should be added apparently.

Comment: It looks like the edit was rejected. I've also since realised that both this answer and the edit I made were insufficient for what I was trying to do. I would delete this question, as it is not clear enough and I have solved my issue through external (non-SQL) means as a workaround. SO will not allow me to delete it, but I've had to un-accept this answer.